# how to perform a task after stopping the test run?

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I was just trying to perform a task after i stop the test run in QTP.

The actual scenario is like this:

I want to login into some site(project internal), perform some task and when i stop the test run, it should automatically logoff from the site.

There is a logoff button too on the web page.

But the challenge is that we have to logoff after we stop the test not before stopping the test run.

kindly help me out, i tried a lot but i am not able to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anthony,i have understood the answer given.But let me be more clear,I am gonna write a code and this will be used by 1000 of people in this org.Now one who runs the script should not be able to edit anything,so when he stops the script manually it should logoff or else the user will edit the data.

Comment: i would be great anthony if you help me out.
Thanks in advance 
And the answer i got was really somewhat helpful for some of my applications.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand why you would want to log off after the test stops, why not have the final step of the test log off?

Also from your question it sounds like you're talking about **manually** stopping the test

> when i stop the test run, it should automatically logoff from the site

This seems to be an un-interesting case, if you're manually stopping the test then you can manually log-off and for automatic test runs (which is the point of automatic testing) behave as is required (log off at the last step etc.)

QTP **does** support closing a browser after the test run (when the test is closed) this is done from the `Record and Run Settings` dialog.

All that being said here's a hacky way to get what (I think) you're looking for, have this as the last step of your test:

```
Browser("Br").Navigate "javascript:setTimeout('document.getElementById(""logout"").click();', 5000); void(0)"
```

What this does is tell the browser to call a [specific function after 5 seconds](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) (5000 milliseconds) (using a [bookmaklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)), the code being called after 5 seconds clicks on the log off button (you'll have to use the correct `id` or otherwise locate the button of course).

As I said I'm not sure I understood your problem so I don't know how helpful this will be.